How can I mask a generic type for intellisense?
Context
I am creating a data validation and query library of sorts. A user can define a schema and make queries, where the results are typed. A minimal example looks something like this:
const g = graph({
  posts: object({
    title: string()
  }), 
  authors: object({
    name: string().optional()
  })
})

const post = query(g, 'posts')
post.title // This is typed as a string!

Problem
However, I am plagued by really complex-looking types. For example, if you hover over g in VSCode, you will see:
const g: Graph<{
    posts: ObjectDef<{
        title: DataAttrDef<string, true>;
    }>;
    authors: ObjectDef<{
        name: DataAttrDef<string, false>;
    }>;
}>

Similarly, if you hover over query:
function query<Graph<{
    posts: ObjectDef<{
        title: DataAttrDef<string, true>;
    }>;
    authors: ObjectDef<{
        name: DataAttrDef<string, false>;
    }>;
}>, "posts">(graph: Graph<...>, _objectType: "posts"): {
    ...;
}

I would love it if hovering over g, showed something a type like MyGraph:
// Desired behavior: 

type MyGraph = typeof g; 

g // Hover over g -> MyGraph

// Hover over query: 
function query<MyGraph, "posts">(graph: MyGraph, _objectType: "posts"): {
    ...;
}

Question
Is there any way to make the intellisense output for g and query look nicer?
I made a smaller, reproducible version of this library and put in on the TS playground. It looks like this:
class DataAttrDef<V, R extends boolean> {
  constructor(public valueType: V, public required: R) { }
  optional(): DataAttrDef<V, false> {
    return new DataAttrDef(this.valueType, false);
  }
}

function string<S extends string = string>(): DataAttrDef<S, true> {
  return new DataAttrDef("string" as S, true);
}

type ExtractValueType<T> = T extends DataAttrDef<infer V, infer R>
  ? R extends true ? V : V | undefined : never;

interface DataAttrsDefs { [key: string]: DataAttrDef<any, any>; }

class ObjectDef<A extends DataAttrsDefs> { constructor(public attrs: A) { } }
function object<A extends DataAttrsDefs>(attrs: A): ObjectDef<A> { return new ObjectDef(attrs); }

type ExtractObjectType<T> =
  T extends ObjectDef<infer A> ? { [K in keyof A]: ExtractValueType<A[K]> } : never;

interface ObjectDefs { [key: string]: ObjectDef<any>; }

class Graph<O extends ObjectDefs,> { constructor(public objects: O) { } }
function graph<O extends ObjectDefs>(defs: O): Graph<O> { return new Graph(defs); }

type QueryResponse<G extends Graph<ObjectDefs>, K extends keyof G["objects"]> =
  ExtractObjectType<G["objects"][K]>;

function query<G extends Graph<ObjectDefs>, K extends keyof G["objects"]>(
  graph: G, _objectType: K): QueryResponse<G, K> { return {} as any; }

// --- 1) hover over g. type looks really large
const g = graph({
  posts: object({ title: string() }),
  authors: object({ name: string().optional() })
})
             // --- 2) hover over `query`. this looks really hard to read
const post = query(g, 'posts')

post.title // This is typed as a string!

I know that Typescript has a known issue about improving type readability. My hope is that perhaps there's some way I can rewrite this validation library, to make the current types more readable.

Thanks @jcalz -- I now include the example inside the post, and got it down to 89 LOC

(see prev comment) You coooould make the type name local to the function body (and therefore private, it will display in IntelliSense as MyGraph but you can't use that type name), as shown in this playground link, but that's not going to work with declaration files, since TS will not use private names for declarations. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

(first comment) Thanks @jcalz. I went ahead and updated the example with your suggestion, so the example is down

(second comment) A local type name is a neat idea, but I don't think it will work for my case. The user defines graph outside of my library, so if I understood correctly, the local type name wouldn't transfer over to their project and their intelisense.

Okay, but then... what are you hoping to see, here? You said "I would love it if hovering over g, showed something a type like MyGraph"? That doesn't make much sense unless MyGraph is something like a local type name. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're looking for?

My hope was that in their code, the user could write something like: type MyGraph = typeof g. Then, when they hovered over their g variable, they would see MyGraph. The main issue I am facing is, because the Graph type is expanded in intellisense, just about all the helper functions I define for them end up looking inscrutable. (for example, hovering over the query function in the playground)

You were hoping the user would manually make their own alias for g? Oh, if you want something like that then you probably need to make it an interface, possibly as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer, if not, what am I still missing?

I think that does the trick @jcalz! My library generates a file for the user, so I could add this manual definition in there for them. I really appreciate your help!

As you saw, using type aliases doesn't always result in your type alias being displayed.  TypeScript will often expand a type alias into its definition, which doesn't help you.  On the other hand, interfaces (and also class instance types), are usually displayed directly.  So if you can get the type of g to be an interface named MyGraph then it should serve your needs:
// some appropriate definition
interface MyGraph { ⋯ }

const g: MyGraph = graph({
  posts: object({ title: string() }),
  authors: object({ name: string().optional() })
})
/* const g: MyGraph */

const post = query(g, 'posts')
/* function query<MyGraph, "posts">(graph: MyGraph, _objectType: "posts"): {
    title: string;
} */

So, we need an appropriate definition of MyGraph. Note that not all types can be written as interfaces (e.g., union types cannot be written as interfaces). But since g is an instance of a class declaration, it will work.  (Indeed, the instance type of a class effectively forms an interface of the same name.)
You could write it out yourself manually, but presumably you want to derive it from typeof g. Well, oops, that won't work above since g is annotated as MyGraph. So what we really want to do is derive it from the return type of graph().  So we could do that in two steps, by first assigning the return value of graph to an intermediate variable:
const _g = graph({
  posts: object({ title: string() }),
  authors: object({ name: string().optional() })
})

And then using that variable to define MyGraph before assigning that value to g:
// some way of deriving MyGraph from typeof _g
interface MyGraph ⋯ typeof _g ⋯ 

const g: MyGraph = _g;

The easiest way to derive an interface type from another type is via interface extension using extends.  Conceptually you'd write
// error, can't do this
interface MyGraph extends typeof _g {}

but unfortunately that's a syntax error because of a syntactic rule that the extended type needs to be a named type. Luckily you can easily work around that by giving a named type to typeof _g and then extending that.  Like this:
type _MyGraph = typeof _g;
interface MyGraph extends _MyGraph { }

Or if you want something a little more reusable, you can just give a generic type name like
type Id<T> = T;
interface MyGraph extends Id<typeof _g> { }

Either way works.

Let's put it all together and verify that it behaves as desired:
const _g = graph({
  posts: object({ title: string() }),
  authors: object({ name: string().optional() })
})
        
type Id<T> = T;
interface MyGraph extends Id<typeof _g> { }
const g: MyGraph = _g;
/* const g: MyGraph */

const post = query(g, 'posts')
/* function query<MyGraph, "posts">(graph: MyGraph, _objectType: "posts"): {
    title: string;
} */

Looks good. The g variable is of type MyGraph, and the information shown on query() refers only to that type.
Playground link to code

For that to work, you'd need to reverse the logic: instead of keeping ObjectDefs in your type parameters, you should keep plain objects with simple values there.
As an example (this might not work fully for your use-case but should give you an idea):
// define allowed shape of values
interface Shape {
  [key: string]: string | Shape
}

// generate type of ObjectDefs based on values, not the other way round
type ObjectDefsOfShape<TS extends Shape> = {
  [K in keyof TS]: DataAttrDef<TS[K], true>
};

// Make the generic type expect simple values instead of ObjectDefs
class Graph<TS extends Shape> {
  constructor(public objects: ObjectDefsOfShape<TS>) { }
}

function graph<TS extends Shape>(defs: ObjectDefsOfShape<TS>) {
  return new Graph(defs);
}

const g = graph({
  posts: string(),
  authors: string()
});

and now, when hovering over g, you get:
const g: Graph<{
    posts: string;
    authors: string;
}>

